# NS_ERROR_ABORT shown in python while tring to start firefox webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

**OS:** Kali Nethunter

**ARCH:** arm64

I am attempting Selenium automation on Android using Firefox ESR and Python Selenium. I have installed geckodriver v0.33 as the webdriver. However, when I execute the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="/home/kali/geckodriver")

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```

I encounter the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__

    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__

    self.start_session(capabilities)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session

    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]

               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_ERROR_ABORT

Stacktrace:

#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:246:28

onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:295:28
```

The Firefox webdriver fails to launch the browser properly, resulting in a crash. I appreciate any assistance in identifying and resolving the issue in my code. Thank you in advance!